# file uploading at client side using Angular 2/4 at angular cli assets folder

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new for angular 4.I wanted to upload image at client side folder,
But I don.t know how to do.
below is the code

```
openFile(event) {
    let input = event.target;
    for (var index = 0; index < input.files.length; index++) {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = () => {
           console.log("result",reader.result);
            var text = reader.result;

        }
        reader.readAsText(input.files[index]);
    };
```

How to read image as blob and write in assets/image/ folder at client Side